# Add javascript file to container control

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning, dotnetnuke-7

Within my skin I have a module container where I want to add a JavaScript file. 
No problem, I use:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="script.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

Only problem is, that the script is located **not** in the skins folder:

```
Portals\_default\Skins\MySkin\script.js
```

but in the containers folder:

```
Portals\_default\Containers\MySkin\script.js
```

Adding above code won't work as it produces a link to the skin folder:

```
<script src="/Portals/_default/Skins/MySkin/script.js?cdv=18" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I use this simple code, it does work:

```
<script src='<%= SkinPath %>script.js' />
```

But then I lose all advantages of the `ClientResourceManagement`!

Looking at the source and the [documentation](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API#New_User_Controls%3a_DnnJsInclude_and_DnnCssInclude_8) there are only two `PathNameAlias` types and none of them are for containers.

The reason why I add the script to the containers folder, is that it's only used in that one container and nowhere else.

*Anyone knows a solution?

Is it easy to implement my own `PathNameAlias`?*

Comment: Can't you just use FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Containers/MySkin/script.js"

Comment: @HansDerks Does DNN automatic replace `_default` then with my current portal number?

Comment: I thought the container was installed in the _default and not in a specific portal. _default has always the same path, when you must use the current portalnumber, then I don't know.

Comment: Where do new installations of a skin package go? In _default or per portal?

Comment: Depends how you install it. If you're a host, you can install it by the Extentions in Host menu and it will install in the _default. If you're just Admin then it will user the current portalnumber

Comment: Ah that's interesting info. Then using hard-coded `_default` won't work.

Comment: Why not use the PortalController and get the current portal settings and use the portal id from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Client Resource Manager API](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API) in your code behind to register scripts and/or stylesheets anywhere in your site directory.

In the codebehind of your module, use this

```
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Parent.Page, "~/Portals/-default/Containers/MySkin/script.js");

            base.OnInit(e);
        }
```

Comment: In combination with [@box86rowh comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398831/add-javascript-file-to-container-control/20732779?noredirect=1#comment28853558_19398831) about current portal id, this mite work.